# WinForms DataGridView Combobox Cells (Entity Framework)

Tags: datagridview, combobox, entity-framework-core, cell

I need to develop simple WinForms application for Sql Data Base with EF.Core v5.013 (code first).
For simplicity I have represented only two classes:

```
// class Server
public class Srvr
    {
        public int Id                { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name           { get; set; } 
     // … some other props
    }

// class Connector
public class Connector
    {
        public int Id               { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int    SrvrId        { get; set; }      // foreign key
        public Srvr   Srvr          { get; set; }      // navigation prop
        
        // … some other props

    }
// So Connector related with Srvr by SrvrId.
```

At GUI:
There are two datagridview controls: dataGridViewSrvrs – for servers (list of Srvr), dataGridViewConnectors - for connectors (list of Connector). And also there is one Update button.

```
        private ApplicationContextDb db;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
             db = new ApplicationContextDb();
             db.Srvrs.Load();
             db.Connections.Load();
             dataGridViewSrvrs.DataSource = db.Srvrs.Local.ToBindingList();
             dataGridViewConnectors.DataSource = db.Connections.Local.ToBindingList();
            
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I need to realize combobox box with Srvr’s names instead of SrvrId’s at dataGridViewConnectors. And when User change value from combobox box and click Update, DB should be updated with correspond Srvrs’Ids([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2qJr.png)).

What is the best practice?

BR

Comment: There is plenty of info on how to set up a data grid view combo box column, and it appears you have everything you need… what have you tried and what is not working? It appears you already have a regular combo box set up. You will want to do something similar using a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. The key properties for setting up the combo box column are the columns `DataSource`, `ValueMember`, `DisplayMember` and finally it’s `DataPropertyName`.